# Error in first function: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

Disclaimer: This is my first time trying to create a function in R.

I have HoltWinters function that looks like this:

```
f <- function(x) {
    y <- ts(x$Million, freq = 4, start = c(2013, 1))
    y.hw <- HoltWinters(y)
    y.pr <- forecast(y.hw, h = 3, level = c(80, 85))
    y.pr
    plot(y.pr)
}
```

It takes a dataframe, converts it to timeseries (`ts`), forecasts and plots the forecast.

I am getting thrown this error:

> Error in x$Million : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I know this is probably a stupid question... but I hope you'll be nice!

**EDIT**

The structure of the dataframes I want to pass to the function:

```
    Quarter Product Million
1   2013-Q1 AAA     4.0
2   2013-Q2 AAA     6.0
3   2013-Q3 AAA     9.0
```

Comment: What's `x`? What's `Million`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg `x` is the dataframe, `Million` is the third column in the dataframe that stores the values that I want to forecast.

Comment: Don't know then, that works for me `df <- data.frame(Million = 1:10) ; f <- function(x) ts(x$Million, freq = 4, start = c(2013, 1)) ; f(df)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Just updated the question for clarification. Glad I'm on the right track at least...

Comment: `f <- function(x) ts(x$Million, freq = 4, start = c(2013, 1)) ; f(df)` with your data set works fine.

Comment: Just restarted it R. It seems to work now! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error appears when you're using `$` on `vectors` or single `numeric` and `integer` values etc, but something other than a `list` or a `data.frame`. Please make sure you're providing a `data.frame` or a `list` in your function. And most definitely, make sure your data set is not a `matrix`.

Comment: I was passing through an already formatted ts object instead of a df. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you've solved it, have a nice day.

Comment: Btw, what are those `numbers` you've mentioned here?

Comment: Single arithmetic values. I have change this to be a little more precise.