# How can I load a package like ''forecast'' in C# via R.NET

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I am trying to use:

```
engine.Evaluate("dataset = read.table(file.choose(),skip=1)");

                     engine.Evaluate(@"install.packages('forecast')");
                    engine.Evaluate("require('forecast')");
                    engine.Evaluate("library('forecast')");

engine.Evaluate("z1 <- ts(dataset,frequency = 15, start=c(2010,11))"); 
                    engine.Evaluate("forecastA <- HoltWinters(z1)");
                    engine.Evaluate("forecast2 <- forecast.HoltWinters(z1,h=6)");
                    engine.Evaluate("plot(forecastA)");
                    engine.Evaluate("plot.forecast(forecast2)");
```

but it says

> Error in object$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please make sure you visit the [tour] page and the [ask] page.

Comment: What is the point of your comment? Please comment only if you have any suggestions

Comment: The point of my comment is to provide assistance to a newcomer and to help improve the quality of your post. Stack Overflow has a built in review mechanism that is designed to help newcomers understand the site and to improve the quality of posts. This makes the site better for everyone, yourself included. Once again, please take the [tour] and good luck with your question.

Comment: I am a week on my laptop with some small breaks looking desparatelly for help and your comment is to check out the tour page? Ok you are right i should but for now i need a small help from someone because i am really exhausted.

Comment: Please keep in mind that nobody on this site owes you anything. Also, you have multiple low-quality posts on Stack Overflow that haven't received much attention. I'm here to tell you there may be a link between what I said in my first comment and your lack of success on this site. None of your posts have met the [mcve] guidelines. I promise you if you improve the quality of your posts, they will elicit a better response from the community. I'll stop commenting here now. Good luck.

Comment: First, do you get the same issue if you execute the code in R directly? See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828114/error-in-first-function-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors

Comment: Aris !!!
You have get any solution ??? kindly please replay...